Vba - extract data from another Workbook
I have two Workbooks. Workbook A and Workbook B. I also have a macro that works, but I cannot figure out, how to be able to write a sheet name in specific cell i Workbook A, and then be able to extract data from Workbook B from sheet with the same sheet name.
What do I have to add to this line or ...?
Workbooks("Workbook B.xlsm").Worksheets("Export").Range("A2:D9").Copy


Is the code located in workbook A? If not, where is it located? What is the cell with the sheet name in workbook A e.g. Sheet1!A2?

The text is located in Workbook A, Sheet1, Cell S2

The code is located in Workbook A

Extract Data From Specific Worksheet

Assuming that the sheet in workbook A is named Sheet1 and the cell with the source sheet name is S2, you could use this one-liner
Workbooks("Workbook B.xlsm").Worksheets(CStr(Workbooks("Workbook A.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S2").Value)).Range("A2:D9").Copy

and continue writing these long unreadable lines (not recommended!).

Or you could introduce some variables and make it more readable (maintainable):


' Retrieve the source sheet name from the destination 'lookup' sheet.
Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("Workbook A.xlsm")
Dim dlws As Worksheet: Set dlws = dwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim dlcell As Range: Set dlcell = dlws.Range("S2")
Dim sSheetName As String: sSheetName = CStr(dlcell.Value)

' Attempt to reference the source sheet.
Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("Workbook B.xlsm")
Dim sws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
    Set sws = swb.Sheets(sSheetName)
On Error GoTo 0

' Check if the source sheet was not found.
If sws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Worksheet """ & sSheetName & """ was not found in workbook """ _
        & swb.Name & """ located in """ & swb.Path & """!", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

' Copy.
sws.Range("A2:D9").Copy
' Continue...


Using these variables will help you write cleaner code in the continuation.

Additionally, if the code is in workbook A, you should replace Workbooks(Workbook A.xlsm) with ThisWorkbook. Then you can rename the workbook as you please and the code will still work.


